# above i want image in layout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Hi in my application I am displaying image and text by using grid view for that i used frame layout inside linear layout.
Now i want above the list view i want to display some image.
can anyone please help me.

**xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <FrameLayout


            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_weight="1" >

        <com.agilerise.hotel.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

             android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            />
        </FrameLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/buttom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:numColumns="3" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add list view in your xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.68" >

</ListView>
```

and create item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="50dip"
  android:layout_height="50dip" 
  android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar" 
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you should use ArrayAdapter in your activity class to create your listview...